# Memory leak with Durable Functions?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-durable-functions

Our first time implementing Durable Functions as we basically have one HttpTrigger that might take up to 3-5 minutes to complete. Therefore we looked into the AsyncHttp pattern which seemed like what we needed. Managed to successfully implement the pattern and it functionality-wise it works. However it came to our attention that the memory consumption now seems a bit odd. As you can tell from the screenshot it is pretty clear when we made the change to Durable Functions. It even triggered a warning in App Insights about a potential memory leak. Question is now whether it is a bug, expected behavior or user-error. Using default configuration. The memory appears to go up even if the application is not being actively used (besides health checks). I don't really see any abnormal memory consumption when running locally.

Sample code:

```cs
[FunctionName("ApproveMemberChangeRequestStart")]
public async Task<AsyncHttpResponse> ApproveChangeRequestStart([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "members-change-request/{ik}/approve")] HttpRequestMessage req, string ik, [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter)
{
    var userIdentity = _userService.GetUserIdentity();
    var instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("ApproveMemberChangeRequestOrchestrator", new ApproveChangeRequestInput(ik, userIdentity));
    return new AsyncHttpResponse(instanceId);
}

[FunctionName("ApproveMemberChangeRequestOrchestrator")]
public static async Task RunApproveChangeRequestOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var input = context.GetInput<ApproveChangeRequestInput>();
    try
    {
        await context.CallActivityAsync("ApproveMemberChangeRequest", input);
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        context.SetCustomStatus(ex.InnerException?.Message);
        throw;
    }
}

[FunctionName("ApproveMemberChangeRequest")]
public async Task ApproveChangeRequest([ActivityTrigger] ApproveChangeRequestInput input)
{
    await _changeRequestService.Approve(input.Ik, input.UserIdentity);
}
```

Memory consumption:
[image]

Comment: My understanding of functions is that it doesn't release the memory back to the OS immediately. Rather it will get released "when it needs it". Which is probably why you're getting the sudden drop off as soon as another request is made

Comment: Do you access disposable resources that you don't dispose?

Comment: I just don't think the memory should go up so much when the service isn't actively being used. And we aren't using any new disposable resources that we weren't before when we didn't have the issue. Unless we are using the orchestration wrong (don't do any more than shown in my example).

Comment: I should add that I think I have come step closer and I think it is due to an error: "task hub name must be specified in host.json when using slots" . Even though I follow the official instructions, I can't seem to get the configuration to work as intended, so I can't be sure for now but still investigating.